# Creating a Palette that dynamically updates button to display Current Alignment Justification

Tags: front-end, dynamic, palettes

I have created palette with 3 buttons next to each other that allow me to change the justification the current cell in the notebooks to: Left, Center, and Right.

I want the buttons to dynamically highlight (in red) whether the cell is currently left, center or right justified.  It was able to get the code below to work in a docked cell perfectly, but not in a palette. I'm not sure why.

```
CreatePalette[
  Grid[{{Tooltip[
      Row[
       Flatten[{
         Button[

            Grid[{{"---"}, {"--"}, {"---"}, {"-"}}, 
             BaseStyle -> {9, "Label", Bold},

             ItemStyle -> 
              If[Dynamic[
                TrueQ[CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[], 
                   TextAlignment] == #]], Red],
             Alignment -> {"Columns" -> {{#}}},
             Spacings -> {"Columns" -> {{0}}, "Rows" -> {{-.8}}}
             ], {SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell], 
             SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
              TextAlignment -> #]}, Appearance -> "Palette",
            ImageSize -> 24] & /@ {Left, Center, Right}}], 
       ImageSize -> {4, 1}*24, BaselinePosition -> Axis], "Alignment", 
      TooltipDelay -> 0]}}]];
```

It does change the justification of the cell but does not dynamically highlight whether the cell is currently left, center or right justified.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to target correct notebook, otherwise it tracks a palette's selection.

```
CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], TextAlignment]
```

should do.

Comment: That did it.  hmmm... Why is it that a docked cell does not require this?  Is it because the docked cell is part of the notebook itself?

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Yes