# Palette to control alignment in formula cells

Tags: formatting, palettes

I would like to create a palette with three buttons:

1. Inserts an alignment marker at the current cursor insertion point (i.e., inserts the character `\[AlignmentMarker]`).
2. Performs the menu function `Format -> Text Alignment -> On AlignmentMarker`.
3. Combines items `1` and `2` into one action.

There don't appear to be Front End Tokens for these functions, and from the advice I have seen on other palette-creation topics ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131466/creating-a-palette-that-dynamically-updates-button-to-display-current-alignment), for example), it's a complicated process. I am afraid I simply didn't understand the mechanics of what was suggested.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on DisplayFormula cells and satisfies all three requirements.  Hope this helps.

```
    CreatePalette[{
   
   Button["Insert Alignment Marker", 
    NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\[AlignmentMarker]"]],
   
   Button["Turn on Alignment",
    
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
     TextAlignment -> AlignmentMarker];],
   
   Button["Turn off Alignment",
    
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell]; 
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
     TextAlignment -> Inherited];],
   
   Button["Insert Alignment Marker and Turn on",
    NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\[AlignmentMarker]"];
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell]; 
    SetOptions[NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]], 
     TextAlignment -> AlignmentMarker];]
   
   }];
```